# When to reference and dereference pointers with member functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, pointers, reference

In the book, I'm learning C++ from, I started to learn about pointers. In the example it gives, it doesn't really specify much as to when to dereference the pointer with the member functions.

```
cout << "Assigning &str to pStr\n";
string str = "score";
string* pStr = &str; //pointer to string object
cout << "str is: " << str << "\n";
cout << "pStr is: " << *pStr << "\n";
cout << "(*pStr).size() is: " << (*pStr).size() << endl;
cout << "pStr->size() is: " << pStr->size() << "\n";
```

why in the second to last line pStr

```
(*pStr).size()
```

needs to be dereferenced while in the last line

```
 pStr->size()
```

pStr doesn't

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't. It's the definition of the operator. `x->y` means `(*x).y`.

Comment: On side note, avoid pointers when you can use references (e.g. `string& rStr = str;`.

Comment: They are two different ways to call a member fucntion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, two statements:

```
(*pStr).size();
pStr->size();
```

are doing the same thing. The pointer is dereferenced in both cases. The difference is just syntactic. This is the way how the language is defined. The `->` operator can be removed from the language without losing any feature. It is sort of syntactic convenience.

Comment: Re *The `->` operator can be removed from the language without loosing any feature* -- The primitive `->` operator can be removed from the language without losing any feature. That's no longer true for classes that overload `operator->`. That's a subtle distinction, so +1 notwithstanding this subtlety.